# Incompatible types using ResponseEntity with Optional

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use Optional map to return response ok, with the value if the value is present and if not i want to return a map with status code 4xx.

```
public ResponseEntity createUrl(@RequestBody String url){
        return service.createUrl(url)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(Collections.singletonMap("error","Invalid url")));
}
```

This says:
 Incompatible types. Required ResponseEntity but 'body' was inferred to ResponseEntity: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, V exist so that Map conforms to Url inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Url lower bounds: Map

But it works like this:

```
public ResponseEntity createUrl(@RequestBody String url){
        if(service.createUrl(url).isPresent()){
            return service.createUrl(url).map(ResponseEntity::ok).get();
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(Collections.singletonMap("error","Invalid url"));
        }
}
```

createUrl method from the service:

```
    public Optional<Url> createUrl(String url){
        try {
            URL myURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
            myURLConnection.connect();
            if(repository.existsByOriginalUrl(url)){
                return Optional.of(repository.getByOriginalUrl(url));
            }else{
                return Optional.of(repository.save(new Url(url,null)));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

I want to avoid using isPresent() and solve this with map() and orElseGet()

Comment: what does exactly `createUrl` returns?

Comment: it returns Optional<Url>

Comment: can you show the method declaration and return type?

Comment: check my answer, and i'm asking about the method consists of this `ResponseEntity` code not the `createUrl` sorry for confusion

Comment: By using optional you cannot return two different types of objects